# Probability of runoff with a given return period

Tags: probability

I've come across an issue, which I cannot figure out how to deal with in a statistical way.

So, let's say I have $n$ events out of $N$ rain-events that produces runoff. Each of the $N$ rain-events has a specific return period. Now, based on the return periods of the $n$ events that produces runoff, how do I determine the propability of runoff for a given return period? 
For instance, 10 out of 100 rain-events produces runoff. Each of the 100 rain-events has a certain return-period, ranging from 1 to 100 years. Based on the 10 events, which is among the 100 rain-events, that produces runoff, how do I calculate the probability of runoff given a return period of e.g. 10 years?

I kinda want a plot, similar to the one below, where you can read the probability of runoff for a specific return period.

[Probability of runoff for return period.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrPti.png)

If you can't answer me directly, it's OK. But if you can give me a hint on what statistical litterature I should look into, it would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Runoff is flood?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Yes! Flood on the surface, in either length or flow units.